# where can I find iphone sdk 3.0 GameKit tutorials for developing P2P applications?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, bluetooth, p2p

I'm starting to develop a p2p applcation for the iphone sdk 3.0. But I'm finding it hard to find good code examples for the bluetooth api.
Anyone knows where I can find this info for newbies?

thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

The Pragmatic Programmers just made available the book [iPhone SDK Development](http://pragprog.com/titles/amiphd/iphone-sdk-development) by Bill Dudney, Chris Adamson, and Marcel Molina through their beta book program.  You can purchase a PDF (and Kindle) version right now, and it contains a detailed chapter on Bonjour and GameKit networking, along with code examples.  Aside from Apple's documentation and sample code, it's probably the best resource you'll find right now.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add the existing samplecode, you can get GKTank from the apple dev site and BeamIt source code here:

http://arctouch.com/beamit/

Answer (score 0):

You can check this tutorial.This tutorial is about how to implement peer to peer bluetooth chat.
http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43502/1954

and also check the book More iPhone 3 Development
Tackling iPhone SDK 3 by
Dave Mark  |  Jeff LaMarche

Answer (score 0):

Adding the Existing Samplecode and geting GTank with BeamIT has help me ,and will help u, also you can find additional support on this:

http://www.algomatik.com/