# bluetooth on iphone

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

Is it possible to send a file using bluetooth programmatically?

Any suggestions or any alternative methods?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is an easy way, but see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427250/how-to-use-bluetooth-to-connect-two-iphone) for information on various ways to create Bluetooth connections for iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect your iPhone to your own embedded device via Bluetooth have a look at the ["Made for iPhone" program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/).