# How to send bluetooth messages between iphones

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

I need to send bluetooth messages between phones.  How do i do that?

Comment: You're more likely to get helpful responses if you take a minute to accept (green checkmark) peoples' answers on your past questions.

Comment: Please search first before posting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427250/how-to-use-bluetooth-to-connect-two-iphone  .. Search results: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iphone+bluetooth